# AUTH LOGIN 503 AUTH command used when not advertised MAIL FROM: 250 OK RCPT TO: 550 Authentication failed DATA QUIT

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, cpanel, whm

Im useing cpanel server , ang i got this class in my script actually i dont know how they are sending email . im getting error in this . 
My Smtp classs is

```
<?php
class Smtp {

var $host = "localhost";
var $port = 25;
var $authenticate = "true";
var $username = "";
var $password = "";

var $smtp = null;
var $connected = false;
var $timeout = 30;
var $error;

var $MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE = 150;
var $NEW_LINE = "\r\n";
var $DEBUG = true;

function send_mail($to, $subject, $message, $from, $charset = "UTF-8", $html = false, $attach = array(), $headers = array()) {
    $success = true;
    $disconnect_on_exit = false;
    $mime_boundary = $this->_generate_boundary();

    if (empty($headers)) {
        $headers = array();
    }

    $to = $this->_parse_address($to);
    $headers[] = "To: {$to[1]} <{$to[0]}>";
    $to_address = $to[0];

    $from = $this->_parse_address($from);
    $headers[] = "From: {$from[1]} <{$from[0]}>";
    $from_address = $from[0];

    $headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
    $headers[] = "Date: " . date("r");
    $headers[] = "Message-ID: " . $this->_generate_id();
    $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n\tboundary=\"" . $mime_boundary . "\"";

    $message_data = $this->_compose($headers, $message, $charset, $html, $attach, $mime_boundary);

    # Connect.
    if (!$this->connected) {
        $success &= $this->connect();
        $disconnect_on_exit = true;
    }

    if ($this->connected) {

        # Send the SMTP commands in sequence.
        $success &= $this->_helo();

        if ($this->authenticate) {
            $success &= $this->_auth();
        }

        $success &= $this->_mail($from_address);
        $success &= $this->_rcpt($to_address);
        $success &= $this->_data($message_data);

        # All done.
        $error = $this->error;
        $this->_quit();

        if ($disconnect_on_exit) {
            $this->disconnect();
        }   
    }

    if (!$success) {
        $this->error = $error;
    }

    return $success;
}

function connect() {
    $this->smtp = fsockopen($this->host, $this->port, $errno, $errstr, $this->timeout);

    if (!empty($this->smtp)) {
        $reply = $this->_get_reply();
        $this->connected = true;

    } else {
        $this->connected = false;
        $this->error = array("Failed to connect.", $errno, $errstr);
        $this->_debug($this->error);            
    }

    return $this->connected;
}

function disconnect() {
    if (!empty($smtp)) {
        fclose($smtp);
        $this->connected = false;
    }
}

function _compose($headers, $body, $charset, $html, $attach, $mime_boundary) {
    $data = "";

    # Process headers.
    if (is_array($headers) && count($headers) > 0) {

        foreach ($headers as $header) {
            $data .= $header;
            $data .= $this->NEW_LINE;
        }

        $data .= $this->NEW_LINE;
    }

    # Normalize new lines.
    $body_data = $body;
    $body_data = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $body_data);
    $body_data = str_replace("\r", "\n", $body_data);

    # Now wrap lines.
    $body_data = wordwrap($body_data, $this->MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE, "\n", true);
    $body_data = str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $body_data);

    # Change new lines back to the required format.
    $body_data = str_replace("\n", $this->NEW_LINE, $body_data);

    # Add the non-MIME text content.
    $data .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.";
    $data .= $this->NEW_LINE;

    # Now add the MIME body part.
    $mime_type = $html ? "text/html" : "text/plain";
    $data .= $this->NEW_LINE;
    $data .= "--{$mime_boundary}";
    $data .= $this->NEW_LINE;
    $data .= "Content-Type: {$mime_type}; charset=\"{$charset}\"";
    $data .= $this->NEW_LINE;
    $data .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";
    $data .= $this->NEW_LINE;
    $data .= $this->NEW_LINE;
    $data .= $body_data;
    $data .= $this->NEW_LINE;

    # Attach the files.
    if (is_array($attach)) {
        foreach ($attach as $attach_file) {

            $attach_filename = str_replace(array("\"", "\r", "\n"), array("-", "-", "-"), 
                    $attach_file['name']);
            $attach_mime_type = $attach_file['mime_type'] ? $attach_file['mime_type'] : 
                    "application/octet-stream";
            $attach_contents = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($attach_file['tmp_name'])));

            $data .= $this->NEW_LINE;
            $data .= "--{$mime_boundary}";
            $data .= $this->NEW_LINE;
            $data .= "Content-Type: {$attach_mime_type}; name=\"{$attach_filename}\"";
            $data .= $this->NEW_LINE;
            $data .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64";
            $data .= $this->NEW_LINE;
            $data .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$attach_filename}\"";
            $data .= $this->NEW_LINE;
            $data .= $this->NEW_LINE;
            $data .= $attach_contents;
            $data .= $this->NEW_LINE;
        }
    }

    $data .= $this->NEW_LINE;
    $data .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
    $data .= $this->NEW_LINE;

    return $data;
}

function _helo() {
    $result = false;

    if ($this->connected) {
        $reply = $this->_send_command("HELO {$this->host}", 250);
        $result = empty($this->error);
    }

    return $result;
}

function _auth() {
    $result = false;

    if ($this->connected) {

        $reply = $this->_send_command("AUTH LOGIN", 334);

        if (empty($this->error)) {
            $reply = $this->_send_command(base64_encode($this->username), 334);
        }

        if (empty($this->error)) {
            $reply = $this->_send_command(base64_encode($this->password), 235);
        }

        if (!empty($this->error)) {
            $this->error[0] = "SMTP error in AUTH";
        }

        $result = empty($this->error);
    }

    return $result;
}

function _mail($from) {
    $result = false;

    if ($this->connected) {
        $reply = $this->_send_command("MAIL FROM:<{$from}>", 250);
        $result = empty($this->error);
    }

    return $result;
}

function _rcpt($to) {
    $result = false;

    if ($this->connected) {
        $reply = $this->_send_command("RCPT TO:<{$to}>", array(250, 251));
        $result = empty($this->error);
    }

    return $result;
}

function _data($data) {
    $result = false;

    if ($this->connected) {
        $reply = $this->_send_command("DATA", 354);

        if (empty($this->error)) {
            $command = "{$data}{$this->NEW_LINE}{$this->NEW_LINE}.";
            $reply = $this->_send_command($command, 250);
        }

        if (!empty($this->error)) {
            $this->error[0] = "SMTP error in DATA";
        }

        $result = empty($this->error);
    }

    return $result;
}

function _quit() {
    $result = false;

    if ($this->connected) {
        $reply = $this->_send_command("QUIT", 221);
        $result = empty($this->error);
    }

    return $result;
}

function _send_command($command, $success_code = null) {

    $error = null;

    if ($this->connected) {

        $this->_debug($command);    
        fputs($this->smtp, "{$command}{$this->NEW_LINE}");

        $reply = $this->_get_reply();
        $code = substr($reply, 0, 3);
        $message = substr($reply, 3);

        if (!empty($success_code)) {

            $success = (is_array($success_code)) 
                ? in_array($code, $success_code) 
                : ($code == $success_code);

            if (!$success) {             
                $command_name = $this->_first_word($command);
                $error = array("SMTP error in {$command_name}", $code, $reply);
            }
        }
    }

    $this->error = $error;
    return array("code" => $code, "message" => $message, "error" => $error);
}

function _get_reply() {
    $reply = "";

    while ($line = fgets($this->smtp)) {
        $reply .= $line;
        if ($line{3} == " ") break;
    }

    $this->_debug($reply);
    return $reply;
}

function _first_word($str) {
    list($line) = explode("\n", $str);
    list($word) = explode(" ", $line);
    return $word;
}

function _debug($message) {
    if ($this->DEBUG) {
        print_r($message);
        echo "\n";
    }
}

function _generate_id() {
    return generateMessageID();
}

function _generate_boundary() {
    return "<<<-=-=-[snet.clf.".md5(time())."]-=-=->>>";
}

function _parse_address($address) {
    $parsed_address = null;

    if (is_array($address)) {
        $parsed_address = $address;

    } else {
        $match = preg_match("/(.*)(\s+)?<(.*)>/U", $address, $parts);
        $parsed_address = $match ? array($parts[3], $parts[1]) : array($address, $address);

    }

    return $parsed_address;
}
   }
    if (!function_exists("generateMessageID"))
  {
function generateMessageID($prefix="40ftrq") {
    $message_id = "<$prefix." 
        . base_convert((double)microtime(), 10, 36) 
        . "." . base_convert(time(), 10, 36) 
        . "@" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . ">";
    return $message_id;
}
      }
```

and MY sending mathode is

```
$smtp = new Smtp();
$smtp->host = "mail.server.com";
$smtp->port = "25"; / testted also 465/587 all port 
$smtp->authenticate = "true";
$smtp->username = "robot@server.com";
$smtp->password = "password";

  $emailer = @sendMail($to, $subj, $msg, $from, $langx['charset']);
   echo $debug;
```

im getting

220-server ESMTP Exim 4.91 #1 Tue, 12 Mar 2019 15:04:48 -0400 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail. HELO mail.server.com 250 server Hello mail.server.com [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] AUTH LOGIN 503 AUTH command used when not advertised MAIL FROM: 250 OK RCPT TO: 550 Authentication failed DATA QUIT

Answer (score 0):

Your mail server does not support authentication, which means it probably gives you sending permissions from your source IP rather than an ID and password. You're also using a string that should be a boolean; set `$smtp->authenticate` to `true`, not `"true"`, but since your mail server doesn't support it anyway, you should be setting it to `false`.

Also, please don't tag questions with `PHPMailer` when you're not using PHPMailer - though perhaps you should be, instead of reinventing the wheel?